# How to get the value of a key value pair from a dictonary which is inside a list and where key starts with a very specific letter

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am unable to parse the value of very specific key in a dict which is inside a list in my program. I have tired the `startswith()` with function but it doesn't seem to work. 
Any idea how should I can achieve the above requirement.
This is how the list of dict looks like

```
[{'dateandtime-ecf9af72-7af8-447e-a071-2ababb0eb139': DatetimeWithNanoseconds(2019, 12, 30, 9, 34, 19, 297000, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'dateandtime-6626eac6-158f-4186-824b-f876de3d0c3a': DatetimeWithNanoseconds(2019, 12, 30, 9, 33, 36, 833000, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'price-4a589779-264a-4396-a527-8fa7067f4c2d': 35.56, 'dateandtime-8a00684f-6fb9-4d6f-b35e-cefb6b09ddb8': DatetimeWithNanoseconds(2019, 12, 30, 9, 34, 10, 387000, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'dateandtime-9c49b315-bd0c-423d-a457-87772e68c9a5': DatetimeWithNanoseconds(2019, 12, 30, 9, 53, 7, 974000, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'price-f7c3364a-8799-4783-af66-f0d07fea0349': 35.56, 'price-5734ea81-b9d4-4616-9f9f-7738cb4b2c5e': 35.56, 'price-398253be-3b34-4cdd-ab22-941b442f78b2': 35.56, 'dateandtime': DatetimeWithNanoseconds(2019, 12, 29, 20, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'price': 0}]
[{'dateandtime-ecf9af72-7af8-447e-a071-2ababb0eb139': DatetimeWithNanoseconds(2019, 12, 30, 9, 34, 19, 297000, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'dateandtime-6626eac6-158f-4186-824b-f876de3d0c3a': DatetimeWithNanoseconds(2019, 12, 30, 9, 33, 36, 833000, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'price-4a589779-264a-4396-a527-8fa7067f4c2d': 35.56, 'dateandtime-8a00684f-6fb9-4d6f-b35e-cefb6b09ddb8': DatetimeWithNanoseconds(2019, 12, 30, 9, 34, 10, 387000, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'dateandtime-9c49b315-bd0c-423d-a457-87772e68c9a5': DatetimeWithNanoseconds(2019, 12, 30, 9, 53, 7, 974000, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'price-f7c3364a-8799-4783-af66-f0d07fea0349': 35.56, 'price-5734ea81-b9d4-4616-9f9f-7738cb4b2c5e': 35.56, 'price-398253be-3b34-4cdd-ab22-941b442f78b2': 35.56, 'dateandtime': DatetimeWithNanoseconds(2019, 12, 29, 20, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'price': 0}, {'dateandtime-20fb2778-2171-4647-a302-a71d5798393d': DatetimeWithNanoseconds(2019, 12, 30, 9, 33, 40, 842000, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'price-b42e4950-f984-4a28-8567-fe8daef6b218': 35.56, 'price-a2351410-e8cf-43c3-8bf6-9fe39cc68758': 35.56, 'price-77af9d5a-081e-4b76-9079-525db471b6cf': 35.56, 'dateandtime-7b2f7096-3c17-4a0d-8a50-b855eaf5f2a8': DatetimeWithNanoseconds(2019, 12, 30, 9, 53, 12, 136000, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'dateandtime-8d1cd71a-04a0-4ea4-9389-db36c94a10f2': DatetimeWithNanoseconds(2019, 12, 30, 9, 34, 14, 349000, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'price1': 10.16, 'dateandtime-600eaadb-dde8-4ad7-91a0-ae836c69f8c2': DatetimeWithNanoseconds(2019, 12, 30, 9, 34, 24, 485000, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'dateandtime1': DatetimeWithNanoseconds(2019, 12, 30, 9, 12, 28, 603000, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'price-ef8f1f44-ea27-41c8-8702-8abc6e7f038d': 35.56}]
```

I want to parse value with the key starting with price.

Comment: please provide your expected output.

Comment: Show the code you tried. The key is just a string so there is no reason why you cant use startswith

Comment: @ChrisDoyle this is the function what I wrote. In summary, I get the collection stored in firestore documents as dict and I store those dicts in a list and I want to pare the value of key starting with price. ```
            user_dict = each_user.to_dict()
            costperday_dict = user_dict['costperday']
            all_user_cost_per_day_list.append(costperday_dict.startswith('price-'))
            print(costperday_dict)```

Comment: @adnanmuttaleb I just want a list of all the prices available in the above lists. Value may not be unique

Answer (score 3):

```py
data = [
    {
        'dateandtime-ecf9af72-7af8-447e-a071-2ababb0eb139': 1,
        'dateandtime-6626eac6-158f-4186-824b-f876de3d0c3a': 2,
        'price-4a589779-264a-4396-a527-8fa7067f4c2d': 35.56,
        'dateandtime-8a00684f-6fb9-4d6f-b35e-cefb6b09ddb8': 3,
        'dateandtime-9c49b315-bd0c-423d-a457-87772e68c9a5': 4,
        'price-f7c3364a-8799-4783-af66-f0d07fea0349': 35.56,
        'price-5734ea81-b9d4-4616-9f9f-7738cb4b2c5e': 35.56,
        'price-398253be-3b34-4cdd-ab22-941b442f78b2': 35.56,
        'dateandtime': 5,
        'price': 0
    }
]

for d in data:
    for key, value in d.items():
        if key.startswith("price"):
            print(value)
```

output

```
35.56
35.56
35.56
35.56
0
```